# What is the meaning of Patty Fenn words: "Throw him under the bus."?

Tags: dialogue, money-monster

In **Money Monster**, What is the meaning of Patty Fenn's words?

> Kyle: Two people I came here to talk to Him and Walt fxxking Camby.
>
> Patty: All right, well, then let's get him Walt fxxking Camby already.
>
> Lee: All right, so let's get him Walt fxxking Camby already.
>
> Patty:  Right. Exactly. **Throw him under the bus.**

Comment: Please ask these kind of questions on http://ell.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: @BCdotWEB he is asking from the context of film, it's perfectly on topic here.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Just because something is said in a movie doesn't mean it is on topic here. It is a common expression and there is clearly zero research since googling it would have revealed its meaning.

Comment: @BCdotWEB so you can say it lack of research not "belongs to ELL"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Throwing someone under the bus" is an act of getting the focus off one's self and onto another.  Think about some of those horrific stories you hear about people getting shoved in front of subway trains.  What happens afterwards?

1. The subway train grinds to a screeching halt, and
2. All the focus is now on the victim, as the perpetrator quietly slips away.

In the case of Money Monster, Patty and Lee want Kyle to focus his anger on Walt Camby instead of Lee.  So they prepare to "throw Walt under the bus" by getting Walt to the bank.

Answer (score 2):

It's a common idiom that the audience is expected to know:

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throw_under_the_bus):

> To throw (someone) under the bus is an idiomatic phrase in American English meaning to sacrifice a friend or ally for selfish reasons. It is typically used to describe a self-defensive disavowal and severance of a previously-friendly relationship when the relation becomes controversial or unpopular.